# The differential relationship chemical potential and the quantity substance

Tags: thermodynamics, metric-tensor

We are familiar with  the heat capacities $ C_P,C_V $; compressibilities $ \beta_T,\beta_S $; and thermal expansion coefficient $ \alpha_P $:

$ C_P = T \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_{P},\;
 C_V = T \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_{V},\; 
 \beta_T = -\frac{1}{V} \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial P} \right)_{T},\;
 \beta_S = -\frac{1}{V} \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial P} \right)_{S},\;
 \alpha_P = \frac{1}{V} \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_{P} $.

What's the similar differential relationship between the chemical potential $ \mu $ and amount of substance $ N $?

$\left( \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N} \right)_{S,V}= ? $

I am learning the fundamental metric geometry of equilibrium thermodynamics, specifically the Weinhold metric. I aim to extend the 2D **thermodynamic vectors** into three dimensions as discussed in this paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3023366.

Understanding the mentioned relationships would likely be beneficial, or do you happen to have any other valuable suggestions?

Comment: Supplemental, although probably not an answer: From $dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP+\mu\,dN$, we have $\mu=(\partial G/\partial N)_{S,V} +S(\partial T/\partial N)_{S,V}-V(\partial P/\partial N)_{S,V}$ and then $(\partial \mu/\partial N)_{S,V}=(\partial^2 G/\partial N^2)_{S,V} +S(\partial^2 T/\partial N^2)_{S,V}-V(\partial^2 P/\partial N^2)_{S,V}$. In other words, to keep entropy constant, and since the introduction of matter brings in entropy and packs the system more densely, we need to incorporate temperature changes and pressure changes as well as Gibbs free energy changes.